# Using ternary operator: "only assignment, call, increment..."

Tags: c#, .net

I have action dictionary defined as:

```
var actions = new Dictionary<string, Action<string, string>>();
```

I put there actions like:

```
actions.Add("default", (value, key) => result.Compare(value, properties[key], Comparers.SomeComparer, key));
...
```

I'm using this code to run it:

```
if (actions.ContainsKey(pair.Key))
{
    actions[pair.Key](pair.Value, pair.Key);
}
else
{
    actions[""](pair.Value, pair.Key);
}
```

It works just fine, but I wanted to use '?' notation to make it shorter:

```
actions.ContainsKey(pair.Key) ? actions[pair.Key](pair.Value, pair.Key) : actions[""](pair.Value, pair.Key);
```

This code shows me error:

> Error 1   Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object
>   expressions can be used as a
>   statement

`actions[pair.Key](pair.Value, pair.Key)` **isn't it a call?** Am I missing something? Is it possible to use '?' notation with action dictionaries? I was trying to find something about that but it's hard to find anything about '?' operator and this error because '?' is ignored by google.

Comment: Your not assigning to anything, also is it really any shorter?

Comment: @Sayse yes I'm not, but there is that I need to do "assignment, call, increment, decrement ..." and I'm doing call. I prefer this notation, but main point is my curiousity. I really do want to know, what is wrong with my call :)

Comment: Statement `(? : )` is not a call - it is a ternary operator and cannot be used alone - it is the same as to put something like `true && false;` at new line.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
actions[actions.ContainsKey(pair.Key) ? pair.key : ""](pair.Value, pair.Key);
```

This will fix your issue.

Comment: I think this code should not replace the original one. Just because it's one line of code it isn't better.

Comment: and why it isn't better my friend?

Comment: it's better not to use ternar operator because you do not get any speed increase but the readability of the code is worse(standard coding practices) just in case someone takes over your code he will have it easier to read if else then ternar operators

Comment: @GoranŠtuc On the contrary, I find this one well within the realm of readability. Everything is unreadable when abused, but if I had to take a guess, I would suggest that blanket bans probably lead to worse code in the long term ;)

Comment: Ternary operators are great and readable if you use them for assignment which they are clearly meant for. I feel in cases like this where you're converting an if statement you have to manipulate your initial mental structure of your logic to account for ternary operators having to return something. Which is taking time for something of no real benefit that other developers will most likely have trouble reading.

Comment: Avoiding ternary operators makes as much sense as avoiding unary operators - avoiding any operators because of their arity doesn't make much sense to me

Comment: @Thomas I'm not saying to avoid ternar operators at all costs, just in cases like these where it kills readability at no benefit at all

Comment: @GoranŠtuc But it doesn't kill readability here (in my opinion). For me the if/else snippet is *verbose* while the ternary one is *concise*. This is a subjective matter, of course.

Comment: @Thomas the point is :
you look at the if else
-5 secs lost
ternar operator:
-10 secs 

the times are made up ofc. but take note that another person looking at this is gonna have to change your code and if he has alot of those time killers it's gonna make it harder for him.
The only thing that could change my mind on this one is if the developer is documenting his code(atleast on a function basis)

The other problem here is that ternar operators return a value which is not needed here, seems like a "let's save lines" instead of anything.

Comment: @GoranŠtuc The point is that you're assuming most people would find the code in this answer difficult to read and would spend more time understanding it than the if/else one. That isn't necessarily true.

Comment: I find this particular use of a ternary operator awful (to obtain the string key of a dictionary). Yak. I stared at it for a minute or so actually especially the part ""](pair.Value, pair.Key) which looked like the complete part after the colon ":".

Answer (score 13):

The [`?:` Conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) is defined as:

> The conditional operator (?:) **returns one of two values** depending on the value of a Boolean expression

Your actions don't *return* a value, so what is the return value of `?:` meant to be?

Answer (score 7):

If you realy have to do it that way, you could try

```
actions[actions.ContainsKey(pair.Key) ? pair.Key : ""](pair.Value, pair.Key);
```

Just to clarify, from [: Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

> The condition must evaluate to true or false. If condition is true,
>   first_expression is evaluated and becomes the result. If condition is
>   false, second_expression is evaluated and becomes the result. Only one
>   of the two expressions is evaluated.

this is equivelant

```
int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
string classify;

// if-else construction.
if (input < 0)
    classify = "negative";
else
    classify = "positive";

// ?: conditional operator.
classify = (input < 0) ? "negative" : "positive";
```

Comment: Thank you Adriaan your explanation == great.

Answer (score 6):

There's nothing wrong with your call, per se. The expression `actions[pair.Key](pair.Value, pair.Key)` is indeed a call. That's not the expression the compiler's complaining about, though. The compiler is referring to the entire conditional-operator expression, which is neither an assignment, call, increment, decrement, nor new object expression, and is therefore not allowed to be a statement by itself.

Alternatives include the following:

- Assigning the result of the expression to another variable, making the conditional merely a sub-expression of the larger assignment statement
- Factoring the conditional into the index expression, so the overall statement is a single call rather than two separate calls.
- Using two independent statements to decide which key to use and then call the function:

  ```
  var key = actions.ContainsKey(pair.Key) ? pair.Key : "";
  actions[key](pair.Value, pair.Key);
  ```

  It still avoids duplicating code, but keeps things more easily readable by not trying to pack everything into one complex statement.

Answer (score 0):

every "? :" statement need to assign to something, meaning that

```
actions.ContainsKey(pair.Key) ? actions[pair.Key](pair.Value, pair.Key) : actions[""](pair.Value, pair.Key);
```

isn't legal because it's not assigning anything.

you can do:

```
object x = actions.ContainsKey(pair.Key) ? actions[pair.Key](pair.Value, pair.Key) : actions[""](pair.Value, pair.Key);
```

and that would be legal if `actions[pair.Key](pair.Value, pair.Key)` and `actions[""](pair.Value, pair.Key);` return a value

Comment: more precise: every ternary expression has to return something